# How to combine regex and get a string from list of String?

Tags: java, regex

I have a list of String like

```java
 List<String> strList = Arrays.asList(new String[]{"pty_abddd_20220220_20220221","pty_hello_20220220_20220221","abc_gecko_20022023_21022023","pty_abddd_20220221_20220222"});
```

From this I want to extract the String with "pty" and the number starting with "*20022023*".
I have tried that and get them separately with this code

```java
String date = "20220221";
        List<String> testList = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> testList1 = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> strList = Arrays.asList(new String[]{"pty_abddd_20220220_20220221","pty_hello_20220220_20220221","abc_gecko_20022023_21022023","pty_abddd_20220221_20220222"});

        for (String str : strList) {
            if (str.contains("pty")) {
                testList.add(str);
            }
        }
        for (String ts : testList) {
            Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("\\d+").matcher(ts);
            if(matcher.find()){
                String str = matcher.group();
                if(str.equals(date))
                    System.out.println(ts);
            }
        }
```

The output will be pty_abddd_20220221_20220222
Is there a way I can combine them with regex, please help thanks

Comment: you're adding the original string `ts`, not a result of the regexp match

Comment: i want to makesure it contains digits,

Comment: You could use a single regex pattern: ^pty.*_20022023_.*

Comment: in that case i am getting all the three, contains "20220221", i need only the ones starts with "20220221"

Comment: @Freddie, to avoid matching strings such as `"pty_abc_920022023_20220221"` and `"pty_abc_200220239_20220221"`, and to be more demanding, you may want to use `^pty_[a-z]+_20022023_\d+$`.

Comment: yes it worked for me for normal strings, but with this example not working   List<String> strList = Arrays.asList(new String[]{"BLU_bus_cash_ticket_sales_20230220_20230221_051427_01.xml","BLU_driver_shifts_20230220_20230221_051424_01.xml","BLU_driver_trips_20230220_20230221_051427_01.xml","BLU_journey_segments_20230220_20230221_051424_01.xml"});
        for(String str: strList){
            Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("^BLU_[a-z]+_20230220_\\d+$").matcher(str);
            if(matcher.find())
                System.out.println(str);
        }

Comment: The number `20022023` is there, but that string does not start with `pty`

Comment: Did you mean something like this? `^pty[^\W\d]*_20220221_.*` https://regex101.com/r/XvNNkh/1

Comment: there are no strings in your example input that start with "pty" and have a number "20022023". Please elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

This will extract strings that start with `pty` and start with number `20022023`:

```
List<String> found = strList.stream()
  .filter(s -> s.matches("pty\\D+20022023.*"))
  .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

But note that none of strings in your example are like that.